# Writing into the same SQL table when using a Threaded task: performance issues

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, amazon-s3, database-performance

I have a threaded task (python 3.6 implementation) that, every morning, loads data for every user present, computes things and then writes the results into the same sets of SQL tables (postgresql 9.5). the writing part takes a whole lot of time and I would like it to be heavily reduced (SQL tables do not have indexes for now). The code is designed so that each user is treated independently but the database is the same.

I would be okay to transition to a no-sql DB (thinking AWS s3) and then finding a solution to then infer the schema for cross-section work. The primary objective is to consume this data - single user mode - in a web application (think fill a dashboard). But transitioning to this solution would require considerable work to set up and I am not even sure it's the best solution since I am new to this infrastructure stuff (staying in SQL would help a lot).

some data that @steve pointed out to be missing: 
(1) per user I delete their previous data from each table and I insert approximately ~10000 records split across different tables 
(2) I load data from other SQL tables (different DB) but the time is not-significant 
(3) I am using an old postgresql release simply because we had some old code left that I was unsure would run on a newer release 
(4) all users are taking ~40 minutes to complete, rising by the day as we get more users [and due to business reasons we absolutely have to reduce that time] 
(5) the task Is structured in a way that loading data (5% of time), computation (30% of time, scales well), deleting&inserting (65%).
(6) the insert are in "bulk mode" relative to each table and user (as well as deletes)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your post is missing any performance data, like how many records are inserted/updated, how many tables have DML and how is the data loaded, how long do the operations take and why are you using such an old PostgreSQL release

Comment: answered some of your questions. hope it's clearer now.

Comment: from an outsider's point-of-view it sounds like what you're doing is a long way from optimal, but there's not much to go on.  e.g. if loading this data from a "different DB" is so fast, why not just do that on-demand rather than repopulating per-user stuff every day. I also personally prefer keeping up to date with new software releases, it seems to be easier in the long run than fewer but bigger and more painful/risky jumps

Comment: are you saying that  loading the data is fast and deleting the data is slow? what is the number of different users? how many rows are deleted and inserted for all the users per day for loading the new data?

Comment: How do you manage transactions? Is each insert run in its own transaction?

Comment: Thank you all for the input. Added some additional info in the body. I agree with the risks of an older release - i Simply did not find the time to test and upgrade (code of my predecessor). I agree what I do Is long fron optimal. Doing on demand Is not a possibility as I believe the complete task will never be completed in a "web" acceptable time within the current infrastructure